# AWS Real-time monitoring resources,

Tags: amazon-web-services, resources, real-time, monitoring

I want to monitor real-time AWS resources, filter by datewise, today how many resources are generated into all accounts.Need a list of active resources into AWS accounts datewise.
Which AWS services is suitable to achieve above result.

Comment: Cloudtrail and billing.

Answer (score 0):

To monitor real-time AWS activity use AWS CloudTrail

https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/

To filter CloudTrail logs by a start and end date and time:

> To narrow the time range for the events that you want to see, choose a
> time range in the time range bar. Preset values are 30 minutes, 1
> hour, 3 hours, or 12 hours. To specify a custom time range, choose
> Custom.
> To remove a time range filter, choose Clear in the time range bar.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/view-cloudtrail-events-console.html

To Understand which aws service *types* are in use across your accounts, use AWS Cost Explorer:

https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/

Related: Create billing alarms

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/gs_monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html